# How do I install Chocolatey packages behind a proxy on Windows 2012 R2 Core?

Tags: .net, powershell, proxy, windows-server-2012-r2, chocolatey

I am currently using Chocolatey in conjunction with Ansible to roll out a number of applications to a mixed Windows/Linux environment.

All the Windows machines, bar one are running as server core installations, and for all the machines except the one with a GUI installed, Chocolatey will not install any applications as it fails to use the proxy.

I have set the proxy environment variables using netsh:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> netsh winhttp show proxy

Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

Proxy Server(s) :  http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:3128
Bypass List     :  <local>;localhost;127.0.0.1;172.16.*;192.168.*;*.domain.local;
```

Also in `%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="HTTP_PROXY" value="http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:3128" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

However, when Powershell scripts scripts call $webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient the proxy element of this object returns nothing:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
PS C:\Windows\system32> $webclient.Proxy

Credentials
-----------
```

I've found that if I manually force the code within functions/Get-Headers.ps1 and functions/Get-webFiles.ps1 to use the proxy then the installs work, however this is not a great workaround to the problem as my Ansible tasks are now fixed to a specific version of chocolatey where I know the workaround works.

Does anyone have any other ideas/solutions to try?

Comment: Did you try to attach proxy manually? `$proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy();
$proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials;
$web = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;
$web.proxy = $proxy`

Comment: `$proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy();` returns nothing, just like System.Net.WebClient. If I were to hazzard a guess, it would be that in a windows core environment somehow because IE isn't in the frame setting the "default" system variables doesn't work right ... but that is a guess.

Comment: Should also add that I've found this issue on [github](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/243), but have not been able to set the config. This seems to get overwritten every time chocolatey is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choco series 0.9.9+ was a total rewrite and hasn't implemented all the things yet, including proxy support out of what you set in IE.

Watch issue https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/243 to know when it available again.

**Update**: proxy support is in Chocolatey now - see https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/Proxy-Settings-for-Chocolatey

Answer (score 1):

run this first

```
choco config set proxy http://proxy_host:proxy_port
```

Comment: could you please provide more details for other users that might not be very familiar this tool. Included expected results and useful parameters

Answer (score 0):

**I tried this in November 2018:**

So, three steps are needed to install and run chocolatey:

1. You need to go and manually download the installation file from:

   ### https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1
2. You need to either:
   a.   edit the ps1 file  OR
   b.  your environmental variables.

You need to have the following variables:

```
    $env:chocolateyProxyLocation = "http://USER:PASSWORD@http://USER:PASSWORD@IP_ADDRESS:PORT
    $env:chocolateyProxyUser = "USER"
    $env:chocolateyProxyPassword  =  "PASSWORD"

   THEY MUST BE AS THEY ARE ABOVE with USER:PASSWORD@PROXY_LOCATION:PORT format.
```

3. You must call the install.ps1 file. 
   You can call it either from Windows-PowerShell ISE or from the CommandLine

You must call your local script!!!  Not the online one, e.g.:

```
file:///E:/softwares/chocolate_install_script/install.ps1
```

Call the following:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>`@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('file:///E:/softwares/chocolate_install_script/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"`

4. And everything will work if you run this with admin provileges

After, you will need to do:

```
choco config set proxy http://USER:PASSWORD@IP_ADDRESS:PORT
choco config set proxyUser bob
choco config set proxyPassword 123Sup#rSecur3
```

Answer (score 0):

This below completely solved this problem...

Kindly follow this link below to resolve this issue.
https://duanenewman.net/blog/post/installing-chocolatey-behind-a-corporate-proxy/

However, for future sake this is the code beneath.

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "[Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials; iex ((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%systemdrive%\chocolatey\bin
```

Just copy and paste the above code to your CMD which you run as an administrator.
And that's all.
Thanks to **Duane Newman** for the originality of the code